# Laravel - Eloquent attach() not working for models

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent

### TL;DR

---

Trying to get three models to interact using eloquent for a rest api.

- User - belongsToMany(pulls)
- Pull - belongsToMany(user) && belongsToMany(boxes)
- Box  - belongsToMany(pulls)

The pull_user table is working perfectly, I can just attach a user after I save a pull. Saving a box works fine but the attach doesn't work/enter anything into the pivot table (I get no errors though).

## The Problem

---

I can't get a pivot table that associates two of my models together to attach() after a save. I have the three models listed above, the pivot is working for pull_user but not for pull_box even though the save for box is working perfectly. I am able to save a box without an error but the association just never occurs (no error).

## The Code

---

pull_box.php

```
class PullBox extends Migration
{

  public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('pull_box', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('pull_id');
        $table->integer('box_id');

    });
  }

  public function down()
  {
    Schema::dropIfExists('pull_box');
  }
}
```

Pull.php

```
class Pull extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['from', 'to', 'runit_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'box_count', 'pull_status', 'audit_status', 'status', 'total_quantity', 'accuracy'];

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
    public function boxes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Box');
    }
}
```

Box.php

```
class Box extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','from', 'to', 'runit_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'pull_id', 'total_quantity', 'status', 'accuracy'];

    public function pulls(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pull');
    }
}
```

BoxController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'user_id' => 'required|integer',
        ...
    ]);

    $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    ...

    $box = new Box([
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        ...
    ]);

    $pull = Pull::whereId($pull_id)->first();

    if($box->save()){
        $pull->boxes()->attach($box->id);
        $box->view_box = [
            'href' => 'api/v1/box/' . $box->id,
            'method' => 'GET'
        ];
        $message = [
            'msg' => 'Box created',
            'box' => $box,
            'pull' => $pull_id
        ];

        return response()->json($message, 201);
    }

    $response = [
        'msg' => 'Box creation error, contact supervisor',
    ];
    return response()->json($response, 404);
}
```

## The Solution

---

I need to know how I can get this association working. I am going to need to add a new layer in under the pull for Item, but I don't want to move one before I solve this. I think that my problem has to stem from a syntactical/logical error on my part but I can't see it. There are a bunch of questions on SO that are very close to giving me a solution, but after reading them I wasn't able to solve my problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try renaming your pull_box table to box_pull, pivot tables on laravel must be in alphabetical order. If you want to use custom name on pivot table you have to extends your pivot, for example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class PullBox extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'pull_box';
}
```

And your many to many relationships:

```
class Pull extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['from', 'to', 'runit_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'box_count', 'pull_status', 'audit_status', 'status', 'total_quantity', 'accuracy'];

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
    public function boxes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Box')->using('App\PullBox');
    }
}

class Box extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','from', 'to', 'runit_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'pull_id', 'total_quantity', 'status', 'accuracy'];

    public function pulls(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pull')->using('App\PullBox');
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple error on my part, thank you for pointing that out. Not sure how I missed that they need to be in alphabetical order in the docs. Also thank you for the info on how to extend pivot to use custom names. Super informative answer

Comment: Thanks! is useful extends pivot tables, also you can add relationships within pivot to other tables, it's very powerful!